# Websphere PARENT_LAST Gives Exception Failed to load webapp

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, websphere, spring-ws

I am using **PARENT_LAST** in the Websphere Deployment. However, I'm getting exception : Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype.

Am I missing anything?

```
[3/25/18 19:10:50:512 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
```

---

```
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:242)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:192)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:380)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:456)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:532)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:406)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
[3/25/18 19:10:50:524 EDT] 00000078 SystemErr     R     ... 98 more
```

Comment: Does your web app contain a copy of the Servlet API?  You can't include that package in a PARENT_LAST loader, because it will clash with the copy the server uses as part of its web container.

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: I had to use a Shared Library. Please follow this link  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/create_shared_library_and_associate_it_with_the_application_server_or_application_on_websphere_application_server?lang=en

Comment: Hey @greencheese, what did you add to the SharedLibrary to get past this problem?

Comment: @Mattiliu, httpcore-4.4.9.jar, httpclient-4.5.5.jar, commons-logging-1.2.jar These were specific to my projects, They might not be specific to your project, but you can try.

Comment: I have had a similar error and the cause was that it was being included in the lib folder of the ear, tomcat server embedded libraries. Removing it solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Jarid, I faced same issue  and resolved by removing javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar from web app lib folder.